# Thread.sleep and hiding buttons

Tags: java, multithreading, button

The problem that I have in my code is that when it runs the `button.setVisible(true);` it won't set the button to visible until all the other `if` statements are passed through which really confuses me.

I'm trying to make simon says, and what this `try`-`catch` does is that it makes the button in the sequence order blink so that the user can know which button it is that follows.

I'm new to programming so any tips and advises are welcome.
Thank you for taking a look!

```
try {

    inputOrder.clear();
    // System.out.println("THIS IS INPUT" + inputOrder);
    Sequence.add(randomNumber());
    int f = 0;
    for (; f < Sequence.size(); f++) {

        //Thread.sleep(2000);

        if (Sequence.get(f) == 1) {
            try {`
                btnNewButton.setVisible(false);
                Thread.sleep(1000); 
                } catch (InterruptedException e1) {

            }
            Thread.sleep(1000);
            System.out.println("it ran here");
            btnNewButton.setVisible(true);


        }
        if (Sequence.get(f) == 2) {
            try {
                btnBlue.setVisible(false);
                Thread.sleep(1000); 
                } catch (InterruptedException e1) {

            }Thread.sleep(1000);
            System.out.println("it ran here");
            btnBlue.setVisible(true);

        }
        if (Sequence.get(f) == 3) {
            try {
                btnYellow.setVisible(false);
                Thread.sleep(1000);
                } catch (InterruptedException e1) {

            }Thread.sleep(1000);
            System.out.println("it ran here");
            btnYellow.setVisible(true);


        }
        if (Sequence.get(f) == 4) {
            try {
                btnGreen.setVisible(false);
                Thread.sleep(1000); 
                } catch (InterruptedException e1) {

            }
            Thread.sleep(1000);
            System.out.println("it ran here");
            btnGreen.setVisible(true);

        }
        System.out.println(Sequence);
        // Order.add(getColor(Sequence.get(f)));
        System.out.println(Order);
        text.setText(String.valueOf(Order.size()));

    }

    btnNextRound.setVisible(false);
} catch (InterruptedException e1) {
    e1.printStackTrace();
}
```

Comment: 1,2,3,4 represent colors

Comment: C#? Java? Common lisp?

Comment: @AK_ probably `java`, since the lower case on `clear()`, and `System.out.println()`

Answer (score 0):

Looks like this happens because you are doing this operation in the UI thread, and it does not have time to execute EventQueue since you force to sleep the UI thread, due to this thread gets chance to actually do the paint once it finish all the sleep calls.

In order to get desired output, I think you should move the sleep logic into a separate thread or to a [`SwingWorker`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/javax/swing/SwingWorker.html). If you moved the logic to a separate thread you need to use the `EventQueue.InvokeLater` to enable buttons.

Answer (score 0):

The way that the Java Swing GUI works is that everything happens one after another. Only when the entire method you posted is finished will the next GUI events (such as the repainting events that need to occur to show that the button's not visible anymore). Doing a Thread.sleep just makes your method take longer to finish. The result is that your UI is frozen because no other events (such as mouse, keyboard, or repainting events) are able to run until after all of your sleep calls.

To perform animation in Java, you should use the `javax.swing.Timer` class rather than using `Thread.sleep`. Below I've posted a quick example of a timer that, when started, will cause a button to flash. This doesn't completely solve your problem (you're also looping, but you really need another timer to actually schedule when the buttons will flash so that they don't all happen at once).

```
import javax.swing.Timer

/**
 * Timer that causes a button to flash (become invisible for 1 second, and then become visible again).
*/
public class ButtonFlashTimer extends Timer {

    private final JButton buttonToFlash;

    public ButtonFlashTimer(JButton button) {
        super(1000, new ActionListener() {
            @Override
            public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
                // This method is called every 1000 ms (until we tell
                // it to stop). This allows us to perform the next "step"
                // in the animation.
                boolean isVisible = buttonToFlash.isVisible();
                if (isVisible) {
                    buttonToFlash.setVisible(false);
                } else {
                    buttonToFlash.setVisible(true);
                    // Once we've flashed, stop the timer (don't keep flashing).
                    stop();
                }
            }
        });
        buttonToFlash = button;
        // Become invisible immediately; the 1000 ms will be the time between the first
        // call to the actionPerformed (which will set it as invisible) and the second
        // call (which makes it visible again).
        setInitialDelay(0);
        setRepeats(true);
    }
}
```